# ID Generating algorithm similar to youtube's generation

Tags: php, algorithm

I am generating random IDs for polls; I have removed enumerating IDs for obvious reasons. I have made my own function for generating the IDs but I'm not sure if it's very 'optimised' or if I'm not doing it the right way. Once I hit near 64^6 polls (probably NEVER going to happen) it would lag. Is this very good?

```
function generateID()
{
    $chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_';
    $id = $this->injectionCSC('$' . substr(str_shuffle($chars), 15, 10), true);

    $link = $this->connect();
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id='$id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        $id = $this->generateID();
    }

    return $this->injectionCSC($id, false);
}
```

$this->injectionCSC($id, false/true); is just a function to get rid of sql injection and html tags. If I'm correct in saying, this current ID generating function can hold up to 1.8014399e+16 polls. And to increase the amount I could either change the special char at the front ('$') or just add another character.

Comment: You need some random id? Use UUID

Comment: @Federico please give an example? I want it to be base64 (has 64 characters to choose from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using pseudorandom number generator to generate your unique ids, choose UUID.

UUIDs v4 are unique and extremely unlikely to collide, unlike your `str_shuffle` implementation. You can use [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid) package to do that. It's simple as write:

```
$uuid4 = (string) Uuid::uuid4(); // something like 16fd2706-8baf-433b-82eb-8c7fada847da
```

You can take the raw bytes to encode them using base64:

```
$id = base64_encode(Uuid::uuid4()->getBytes());
```

Comment: Is this acceptable? `$rawId = sprintf($yearIdentifier . '%04X%04X%04X%04X%04X%04X%04X%04X', mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0,
        65535), mt_rand(16384, 20479), mt_rand(32768, 49151), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535), mt_rand(0, 65535));

        echo('$' . substr(base64_encode($rawId), 32, 9));`

Comment: I don't think so, at that point just generates 128 bits of random data with `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);` and then convert them in base64 -> `$id = base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));`

Comment: Thanks @Federico , new code =

`$id = substr($this->getYearIdentifier() . str_replace('/', '_', str_replace('=', '-', str_replace('+', '-',
                base64_encode(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(15))))), 0, 10);

        $link = $this->connect();
        if(mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM polls WHERE id='$id'")) > 0) {
            $id = $this->generateID(); //recursion until it's not used.
        }

        return $id;`